# Using JavaScript and CSS selector, strings such as nonfiction and fiction are both returning true and shouldn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

http://jsbin.com/aguver/17/edit
I found this code here after much searching. It is setting the class of active and removing it from where it was. The issue is that it is changing 2 links to red when it should be only the one.

With regex something like `/^\w/` may work, but not as designed in the code since its a variable placed into a css selector. Its searching/selecting too vaguely for my purpose.

Thanks.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>demo by roXon</title>
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  *{margin:0;padding:0;}
  ul{list-style:none;}
  a{text-decoration:none;}
  a.active{color:red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
     <ul id="books">
         <li><a href="nonfiction">Nonfiction</a></li>
         <li><a href="fiction">Fiction</a></li>
     </ul>  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```js
var url = 'http://www.domain.com/fiction'; //<-- too similar to nonfiction

//actually it just checks the last character, I need regex maybe

var link = url.split('/').slice(-1);

document.write(url.split('/').slice(-1));

$('#books li a[href$="'+link+'"]').addClass('active');
//Script is supposed to select the active link via the url and giving it a class attribute
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code directly, so that people don't need to go to a third party site to read it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? The question is vague and concentrates more on what doesn't work than what you're trying to do. Maybe whip up some mock screen shots of what's supposed to happen?

Comment: Part of the problem you're having is the selector. You're using jQuery's `$=` attribute selector, which is the "ends with" selector. And both "fiction" and "nonfiction" end with "fiction". Consider a more exact match.

Comment: @founddrama: +1, the tin couldn't have said it any better

Comment: As you are comparing URLs, why not just compare the whole URL?  Any "contains" or "ends with" check will always have edge cases where they can incorrectly match something else

Comment: Heh maybe all that searching fried my mind a bit, url match works great. Thanks.